# MSBuild get all project referencing/using a project

Tags: msbuild, build-process, build-automation

We want to setup a build process to prevent breaking changes on our branch. We have a common library/project being referenced by multiple projects. So that, when a change is made on this common library, all other projects which use it may also build and check for breaking changes. So far, using MSBuild, we have been able to do the other way around. From a project, we can gather all its dependencies. But how could I get all the projects that reference/use the common library with msbuild?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to drop this common library to a common folder under your branch whenever it builds and refer this from there in other projects.

Otherwise, I am not sure whether msbuild does have a support to identify the places where a binary is being referred. If possible also it will be a time consuming process depending on the size of your branch and it adds unnecessary overhead to your common library build and it will seriously affect the maintainability of your branch's build process in future once it starts consuming this common library in multiple other places.

Answer (score 0):

That would be some work if you wanted to do some "push" notifications.

The cheap trick would be that (as a last step in the build process) of the CommonLibrary, would be to do a source-code update in each of the dependent projects.  Like a dummy file.

```
.\MySolution1.sln
.\MyBuildTriggerFile1.txt
```

and then

```
.\MySolution2.sln
.\MyBuildTriggerFile2.txt
```

(etc, etc).

And have the CommonLibrary build process go and do some kind of quick update and check-in on the dependent projects.

The good here would be, that is relatively easy to implement.
The bad here is that, you'll have to manually keep the list updated in the CommonBuild project.
The other good is that..you're not actually doing the builds, you're just sending a little tiny message saying "something happened".  So the CommonBuild library won't be bogged down.

Then, your dependent projects could be set to "build on change", and then you'd know fairly quickly.

......

If you want it "all automatic" and "all dynamic", you gonna have to do some work with a custom MSBuild task.

You'd have to start pulling csproj files, parsing them, and then link them back the CommonLibrary.

[XPath and *.csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745029/xpath-and-csproj/12848854#12848854)

YOUCH.  That's alot of work.

.......

I would take a middle ground approach.

Use the "trigger file" system......(suggested above).......and have the code build either once a night or "on every check in"......

Anyway.  There's an idea.  But I don't know of anything out of the box.

............