# c# - How can I programmatically check that a reference is configured correctly in a solution

Tags: c#, dll, reference, msbuild, csproj

We are having some build errors and we need to manually fix the references.
I would like to programmatically check that project references are defined instead of dll references:
Thus go over all the references in a solution and for each project, check that the references are defined correctly. This way the relevant dependencies will be configured correctly.

Does anybody know of an existing solution? I would like a validation tool that will run before the gated check-in.

Comment: I think you mean "programmatically"

Comment: i guess you can't use any class if it's reference not declared or is not exist

Comment: lol. Problematically is definitely better.

Comment: May I ask what is wrong in DLL references ?

Comment: If you add a dll reference to a project that exists in the solution, then when building you might get a build error because there is no dependency between the projects. The dll that are referencing might not have been built yet. see the following link from more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817675.aspx

Comment: what dependency between projects? it MUST have been built since you reference to a dll.. make sure of your CopyLocal setting and make sure that you dont reference the dll path with /Debug or /Release use $(Configuration) to determine the compile mode

Comment: in addition make a dependency built between project, there is build order for this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have written such a tool for processing our ".csproj" files. My tool recursively descends through a folder hierachy, processing each ".csproj" file to verify that it conforms with our standards (such as requiring Code Analysis to be turned on, Warnings as Errors, strong-name signed and so on).

Anyway, I recently rewrote a lot of it to use Linq-to-XML to process the files which turned out to be a lot easier than how I did it when originally written seven years ago...

The core of CSProj handling is done by a class which expects as input (via the constructor) the full pathname of a ".csproj" project file.

It uses Linq-to-XML to parse various parts of the file. Have a look at it - hopefully it will get you started.

I also recommend using Linqpad when trying out various XML queries to get at the various bits of a .csproj file.

This code is somewhat specific to our requirements, but it should give you a starting point.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace CreateMSBuildProject
{
    /// <summary>Encapsulates a ".csproj" file.</summary>

    sealed class CSProj
    {
        /// <summary>Encapsulates information about a particular build configuration.</summary>

        public sealed class BuildConfiguration
        {
            public BuildConfiguration(XElement configuration)
            {
                // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException

                OutputPath             = configuration.Element(_ns + "OutputPath").Value;
                WarningLevel           = warningLevel(configuration);
                CodeAnalysisRuleset    = configuration.Element(_ns + "CodeAnalysisRuleSet").Value;
                TreatWarningsAsErrors  = isTrue(configuration.Element(_ns + "TreatWarningsAsErrors"));
                IsCodeAnalysisEnabled  = isTrue(configuration.Element(_ns + "RunCodeAnalysis"));
                IsCodeContractsEnabled = isTrue(configuration.Element(_ns + "CodeContractsEnableRuntimeChecking"));

                // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
            }

            public bool IsDebug
            {
                get
                {
                    return (string.Compare(OutputPath, "bin\\debug\\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
                }
            }

            public bool IsRelease
            {
                get
                {
                    return(string.Compare(OutputPath, "bin\\release\\", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
                }
            }

            static bool isTrue(XElement element) // Defaults to false if element is null.
            {
                return (element != null) && (string.Compare(element.Value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
            }

            static int warningLevel(XElement element) // Defaults to 4 if not set.
            {
                var level = element.Element(_ns + "WarningLevel");

                if (level != null)
                    return int.Parse(level.Value);
                else
                    return 4; // Default warning level is 4.
            }

            public readonly string OutputPath;
            public readonly string CodeAnalysisRuleset;
            public readonly bool   IsCodeAnalysisEnabled;
            public readonly bool   TreatWarningsAsErrors;
            public readonly bool   IsCodeContractsEnabled;
            public readonly int    WarningLevel;
        }

        /// <summary>Encapsulates information about a referenced assembly.</summary>

        public sealed class AssemblyReference
        {
            public AssemblyReference(XElement reference)
            {
                Include = reference.Attribute("Include").Value.Split(',')[0]; // Get rid of stuff after the first ","

                var hintElem = reference.Element(_ns+"HintPath");

                if (hintElem != null)
                    HintPath = hintElem.Value;
                else
                    HintPath = "";
            }

            public readonly string HintPath;
            public readonly string Include;
        }

        /// <summary>Constructor.</summary>

        public CSProj(string csprojFilePath)
        {
            if (!isValidProjFilePath(csprojFilePath))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("csprojFilePath", csprojFilePath, "File does not exist, or filename does not end with '.csproj'.");

            // ReSharper disable PossibleMultipleEnumeration

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(csprojFilePath);

            var propertyGroups = getPropertyGroups(doc);

            _projectFilePath              = csprojFilePath;
            _outputType                   = getOutputType(propertyGroups);
            _assemblyName                 = getAssemblyName(propertyGroups);
            _targetFrameworkVersion       = getTargetFrameworkVersion(propertyGroups);
            _projectDependencies          = getProjectDependencies(doc);
            _targetFrameworkProfile       = getTargetFrameworkProfile(doc);
            _xmlDocumentationFiles        = getXmlDocumentationFiles(doc);
            _buildConfigurations          = getBuildConfigurations(doc);
            _assemblyReferences           = getAssemblyReferences(doc);
            _anyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled = getAnyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled(doc);
            _platformTargets              = getPlatformTargets(doc);

            // ReSharper restore PossibleMultipleEnumeration
        }

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>The project output type, e.g. "WinExe" or "Library".</summary>

        public string OutputType { get { return _outputType; }  }

        /// <summary>The project's output assembly name.</summary>

        public string AssemblyName { get { return _assemblyName; } }

        /// <summary>The target framework version, or 0.0 if not set.</summary>

        public double TargetFrameworkVersion { get { return _targetFrameworkVersion; } }

        /// <summary>The project dependencies - not to be confused with assembly references!</summary>

        public IEnumerable<string> ProjectDependencies { get { return _projectDependencies; } }

        public IEnumerable<string> XmlDocumentationFiles { get { return _xmlDocumentationFiles; } }

        public IEnumerable<BuildConfiguration> BuildConfigurations { get { return _buildConfigurations; } }

        public string TargetFrameworkProfile { get { return _targetFrameworkProfile; } }

        public IEnumerable<AssemblyReference> AssemblyReferences { get { return _assemblyReferences; } }

        public bool AnyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled { get { return _anyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled; } }

        public string ProjectFilePath { get { return _projectFilePath; } }

        public string[] PlatformTargets { get { return _platformTargets; } }

        #endregion Properties

        //—————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

        static string[] getPlatformTargets(XDocument doc) 
        {
            var result = (from item in doc.Descendants(_ns + "PlatformTarget") select item.Value).ToArray();

            if (result.Length > 0)
                return result;
            else
                return new []{"AnyCPU"}; // If "PlatformTarget" is not specified, it defaults to "AnyCPU".
        }

        static IEnumerable<XElement> getPropertyGroups(XDocument doc)
        {
            // ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
            return doc.Element(_ns+"Project").Elements(_ns+"PropertyGroup");
            // ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
        }

        static string getOutputType(IEnumerable<XElement> propertyGroups)
        {
            return propertyGroups.Elements(_ns+"OutputType").First().Value;
        }

        static string getAssemblyName(IEnumerable<XElement> propertyGroups)
        {
            return propertyGroups.Elements(_ns+"AssemblyName").First().Value;
        }

        static double getTargetFrameworkVersion(IEnumerable<XElement> propertyGroups)
        {
            var targetFrameworkVersion = propertyGroups.Elements(_ns+"TargetFrameworkVersion").FirstOrDefault();

            if (targetFrameworkVersion != null)
                return double.Parse(targetFrameworkVersion.Value.Substring(1)); // Skip first character, which is "v"; eg like "v3.5"
            else
                return 0;
        }

        static string[] getProjectDependencies(XDocument doc)
        {
            return 
            (
                from item in doc.Descendants(_ns + "ProjectReference")
                select item.Attribute("Include").Value
            )
            .ToArray();
        }

        static string getTargetFrameworkProfile(XDocument doc)
        {
            var targetFrameworkProfile = doc.Descendants(_ns + "TargetFrameworkProfile").FirstOrDefault();

            if (targetFrameworkProfile != null)
                return targetFrameworkProfile.Value;
            else
                return "";
        }

        static string[] getXmlDocumentationFiles(XDocument doc)
        {
            return
            (
                from item in doc.Descendants(_ns+"DocumentationFile")
                select item.Value
            )
            .ToArray();
        }

        static BuildConfiguration[] getBuildConfigurations(XDocument doc)
        {
            var configGroups = from item in doc.Descendants(_ns+"PropertyGroup")
                               where item.Descendants(_ns+"OutputPath").Any()
                               select new BuildConfiguration(item);

            return configGroups.ToArray();
        }

        static AssemblyReference[] getAssemblyReferences(XDocument doc)
        {
            var references = from item in doc.Descendants(_ns + "Reference")
                             select new AssemblyReference(item);

            return references.ToArray();
        }

        static bool getAnyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled(XDocument doc)
        {
            return doc.Descendants(_ns + "CodeContractsRunCodeAnalysis")
                .Where(item => item.Attribute("Condition") == null) // Some of these have a "Condition" attribute, which is OK.
                .Any(item => string.Compare(item.Value, "true", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0);
        }

        static bool isValidProjFilePath(string projFilePath)
        {
            return 
            (
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(projFilePath) 
                && (projFilePath.EndsWith(".csproj", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || projFilePath.EndsWith(".vbproj", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                && File.Exists(projFilePath)
            );
        }

        static readonly XNamespace _ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

        readonly bool _anyStaticCodeAnalysisEnabled;

        readonly string _projectFilePath;
        readonly string _outputType;
        readonly string _assemblyName;
        readonly string _targetFrameworkProfile;
        readonly double _targetFrameworkVersion;

        readonly string[] _projectDependencies;
        readonly string[] _xmlDocumentationFiles;
        readonly string[] _platformTargets;

        readonly BuildConfiguration[]     _buildConfigurations;
        readonly AssemblyReference[] _assemblyReferences;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  I was going to post some basic csproj linq-to-xml parsing....but you put your version on steroids.  Upvote.

Comment: MatthewW.  Check this url.  You may be able to determine "DLL Reference By Local", "DLL Reference by GAC", and "Reference by Project".       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745029/xpath-and-csproj/12848854#12848854

Comment: Microsoft offers a class that does a lot of this for you so you don't have to deal with parsing xml yourself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.evaluation.project.aspx