# Duplicate files in csproj file Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

Somehow I am seeing duplicate files in my solution. I dig into it and found that somehow, there are two entries for some files in `.csproj` file. That's why two files are shown that is actually one file. I have to find for all the files in `.csproj` file. Is there any easy way to remove those entries from `csproj`? And also can anyone let me know the cause of this?

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021057/find-and-remove-duplicate-entries-in-csproj-file?lq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200484/tfs-merge-creates-duplicate-entries-in-solution-project-files) on StackOverflow, this might happen when TFS (or other version control systems) edit a project file e.g. during a merge operation.

Anyway, you have probably opened a csproj file and seen that [it's just an XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/understanding-the-project-file), with files being listed in elements like those below:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
   <Compile Include="Controllers\ContactsController.cs" />
   <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
   ...
</ItemGroup>
```

[One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41882040/5480409) to the question I linked above also provides a reference to a deduplication Powershell script on GitHub, which I haven't tried and cannot guarantee for, although I don't see what harm it could do.

If your files are not too many, you can just look for the following string

```
.cs" />
```

with a text editor like [PsPad](https://www.pspad.com/en/), have it list the results and remove double entries by hand. Of course, before doing anything, backup your file.

[Another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575417/5480409) involves selecting all duplicated files in your project, clicking "Exclude from project" and then "Show all files" and include them by hand.

Comment: How about copying file in a simple text file, read that file through code, find duplicate entries using code (simple linq or anything).?

Comment: Of course you can, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218163/parse-csproj-via-c-sharp-cannot-parse-itemgroup?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to begin with. Personally I would resort to writing code only if you have lots of duplicates (>30) or if this problem is recurring.

Comment: Right now I just deleted those files from project and included them again.

Comment: My project is quite complex. If I have to manually go through the project and remove duplicates, so be it. But my concern is that I still don't know what triggered the duplication and it will just happen again.

Comment: Also with projects that are a combination of ASP.NET and Angular the project file doesn't contain references to the individual files that are apart of the client side code that are duplicated. I am not sure what is causing the duplication in this case.

Comment: It seems to have to do with lines in the .csproj like these:

  <ItemGroup>

    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->

    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />

    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />

Comment: Without restarting VS 2022, I excluded from project all duplicated files and clicked twice at **Show All Files**; they gone.