# Duplicate files in Visual Studio when I deleted folder from a project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, csproj

Recently I have this issue in Visual Studio. I needed to delete a folder from a project in Visual Studio. When I deleted the folder, many of files got dupes in `csproj`. I wanted to know what should be the cause for this. I got some solutions on my previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49691209/duplicate-files-in-csproj-file-visual-studio).
But they were about `TFS`. Right now my project is not on any deployment tools (like neither `TFS`, nor `HG` or any other).

Thanks.

Comment: Let's start with basic questions: What specific folder did you delete? How are you deleting it? Where exactly are you finding "dupes"? Can you give a clear example?

Comment: @Jazimov: I deleted folder for view. The controller for that view was deleted before.  Select the folder and press delete. Did not exclude it. Generally javascript, less, css files are duplicating. And also images.